# How do I create a partial search filter (/^) in mongoDB + mongoose combination?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
{ "id" : "1.2.1", "name" : "abc1" }
{ "id" : "1.2.3", "name" : "abc2" }
{ "id" : "1.2.2", "name" : "abc3" }
{ "id" : "1.2.1", "name" : "abc4" }
{ "id" : "1.2.4", "name" : "abc5" }
```

I want to get all records that starts with id = 1.2. So in shell I can happily use:

```
db.collection.find({id : /^1.2/})
```

And it works fine. But now from node.js / mongoose when I try to issue the same find, I want this 1.2 to be a variable. 
My problem is I can't do something like

```
var q = {"id" : \/\^ +  id + "/"};
```

Get illegal token error. This may be as simple as JS escaping technique that am not aware of.
Any help would be highly appreciated and save mongodb from multiple queries :)

While this is more a generic mongoDB find question, if someone can hint me towards how I can use mongoose for like operator, that would be great.
By the way, I don't want to use regEx here because of performance consideration.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do realize that the query you are doing **is** a regex operation from your first example. But it seems you are having a problem of how to translate this into something dynamic. This is where the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator syntax comes in:

```js
var id = "1.2";

db.collection.find({ "_id": { "$regex": "^" + id } })
```

That is generally how you approach using the operator outside of the mongo shell.

That catch with using a regex is when you **do not** anchor to the beginning of a field like you have then you are scanning a full index or possibly even the collection.

When you **do** anchor, the index **can** be bound by a lexical match to restrict what is scanned. In your case here it will be the lexical bounds of "1.2" to "1.3".

Comment: Thanks Neil - I shall give regEx a try. But by anchoring regex to beginning do u think it prevents full index scan and actually produces same result as dynamic query ? If that's the case - it makes my life much easier :) I was in an impression regex means no index - and hope I am wrong

Comment: @pagladasu I believe a regex that is beginning-anchored and contains no wildcards will use an appopriate index.

Comment: just a follow up - is there a way to check whether it is using index and how - like a query plan kind of thing ?

Comment: @pagladasu Yes. See [`.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) in the documentation. Of course the field must be indexed as well.

Comment: It works well for single regex expression --> 
var q = {active: 1, "id":  { "$regex" : '^2.' } };

But this fails -->
var q = {active: 1, "id":  { "$regex" : { "$in" : [ '^2.', '^3.' ] }} };

However same query works fine in shell / roboMongo :( any idea ?